# In the current canon, who took over after Padmé as senator of the Naboo system?

Tags: star-wars, padme

**I have been trying to find who took over the Naboo seat after Padmé died during RoTS.** I have found information on who was there before her from the *Queen's Shadow* book.

And I know in Legends it was eventually taken over by her niece but I can't find anything on who was the senator right after her death in either of the canons for that matter. I am assuming Jar-Jar had to assume some responsibilities for some time.

**Was he left there and promoted from just a representative to full fledged senator? Or was someone else eventually sent?**

Comment: It was Jar Jar Binks followed by Pooja Naberrie according to the Star Wars Encyclopedia. I don't think there's a *canon* confirmation of who came after Padmé, nor that Jar Jar became the full Senator.

Comment: "*While the
two scripts are similar, small variances differentiate the Royal
Script from the Naboo Futhark, a fact made eminently clear when
**Senator Binks of Naboo** famously misinterpreted the name of the
Palazzo's Heroine Hall as "Hero in Hell" during Queen Apailana's
state visit to the world.* - [Hyperspace Article: The Written Word](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&ved=0ahUKEwioid2wlNnQAhWGORQKHdcvAQgQFghHMAs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdromaskald.zapto.org%3A2665%2Fget%2Fpdf%2F1192&usg=AFQjCNHlLZJmd3sLftS1Q7s81S4fn7ECPQ&sig2=0g9aQYHKNowg9UlznXYlMw), etc

Answer (score 3):

In the (canon) book *[The Legends of Luke Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Legends_of_Luke_Skywalker)*, it is confirmed that Jar Jar became the Senator of Naboo.

> "Speaking of Naboo sardine fritters, did you know that Senator Jar Jar Binks and Lord Vader were the same person?"

Comment: Notably, this book is a "*collection of myths and tall-tales about the legendary Jedi Luke Skywalker*". All of the narrators are fairly unreliable.

Comment: Yes, but currently this is the best we have to go on in canon.

Comment: I don't disagree, but a little bit of a warning/disclaimer probably would have been useful.